# jQuery Countdown compact with two significant digits

Tags: jquery, countdown, significant-digits

When I display the compact countdown with two significant digits it shows something like:

"2d 12:00:00" and minutes/seconds stay at "00" forever. How can I get it to display something like: "2d 12h" instead?

Strangely enough if I use the non-compact output, everything works as expected, i.e. it shows only "2 days 12 hours".

Comment: We can just guess. Any code to show?

Comment: Not sure what code you mean. I call it as `code`<span class="countdown"><?=Date::showTimeDifference($v['endDate'])?>
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?=Date::secondsDifference($v['endDate'])?>" /></span>

Comment: ... and in jquery.countdown.js I have: "format: dhms" (all low caps), "compact: true", "significant: 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the compact option has a fixed layout. In order to achieve what I want, a custom layout needs to be created as follows

`layout: '{d<}{dn}{dl}{d>} {h<}{hn}h{h>} {m<}{mn}m{m>} {s<}{sn}s{s>}'`

Answer (score 0):

It's imortant to use layouts and there 'mnn' for minutes, 'snn' for seconds etc.
Look the code below:

```
$('#compactLayout').countdown({
    until: liftoffTime, 
    compact: true, 
    layout: 'just <b>{dn} {dl} {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}</b> {desc}', 
    description: 'to wait'
});
```

Use only 'sn' instead 'snn'